# Nuget client doesn't include credentials for download request

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget

I have this issue which is driving me nuts :/ .
We have made some custom powershell modules which are managed by a nuget server with credentials.
 During my tests in a windows machine, I could register our external repository just fine and also call the **find-module** function which list the modules included in our repository, I'm using credentials when I registered the repository and also to call the **find-module**. 
The problem is when I call the **install-module** I get an unauthorized exception since Nuget client didn't include the credentials even if it's included in the powershell function call. 
 
**update:** 
The server that we talked to to get the customized modules is using the following docker-image https://github.com/idoop/docker-nuget-server 
the commands I was using to register our custom repo are:

```
    # POWERSHELL V5.1
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
    [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Register-PSRepository -Default -InstallationPolicy Trusted

    Register-PSRepository -Name 'EXAMPLERepository' -SourceLocation 'https://example/nuget/' -PublishLocation 'https://example/nuget/' -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $credObject

    Find-Module -Name 'MyModule' -Repository 'EXAMPLERepository' -Credential $credObject 
    # this works

    Install-Module -Name 'MyModule' -Credential $credObject  -Force 
    # this doesn't 
    # it gives this error
    # End of Central Directory record could not be found 
    # which is an authorized response from the server
    # when we checked the logs, the credentials are not included 
    # in the api call for download
```

Any clue or a workaround for this will be much appreciated =)

Comment: Please post the minimal script to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @TobiasBruckert I'm sorry for my late reply, I wasn't available yesterday, I've updated my post